# Error function in simulation of normal random variates

Tags: normal-distribution, simulation

I was wondering if there is any benefit to using the inverse error function as opposed to the inverse normal in simulating normal random variates. Increased accuracy for probabilities way in the tails would be nice.

I was not able to find any information about this online so thanks!

Comment: If the inverse normal is well implemented you should be able to use it with a small fiddle for dealing the upper tail that should give you essentially equivalent accuracy.

Comment: Since the two functions are essentially the same, what exactly are you trying to ask?

Comment: Matlab gives some tips without justification that using the error function provides increased accuracy in some cases. I was wondering if there is something documented about when it should be used or if it is always preferable.

Comment: Please state the exact tips from MATLAB. Provide links as appropriate.

Comment: Here is the link, the tip involves some typeset math, https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/erf.html